# Scrapy global name substring is not defined

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, substring

I'm trying to extract a particular piece of text with Scrapy.

Here is my code

```
        item['movie_director'] = movie.xpath(substring-before(substring-after(span[1]/text(), 'Director :  '), '.')).extract()
```

The format is :
  *Director : Director's name.*

And I want to extract only this : 
  *Director's name*

But when I set the crawler, I have this error : global name 'substring' is not defined.

I thought the use of substring was included. Is there a way to import this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you post the traceback you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xpath` expression needs to be a `string`, i.e. put it under quotes :

```
item['movie_director'] = movie.xpath("substring-before(substring-after(span[1]/text(), 'Director :  '), '.')").extract()
```